# How Do I Write A Do-Loop That Creates A Graph For Each Unique Person?

Tags: sas, do-loops, sgplot

I am trying to run through a large data set and create a simple scatter plot for each person.  I would like to run this in SAS using a do loop and proc sgplot.

My dataset is the following:

```
 Person     Date          QTY      Brand
  Jim   | August 2015   |   20    |  Pepsi
  Jim   | AUgust 2015   |   20    |  Coke 
  Jim   | October 2016  |   30    |  Pepsi
  Jim   | November 2016 |  40     |  Sprit 
  Susan | Sept. 2015    |   20    |  Dr.Pepper
  Susan | Dec. 2016     |   10    |  Sprit 
  Helen | Jan. 2016     |   20    |  Coke
  Helen |  Feb.2016     |   30    |  Pepsi
```

There are many distinct people (n=100). I want to create a scatter plot for each unique person that shows the date on the x axis, and quantity on the y.  Then I would like the points grouped by brand.

Currently my code is:

```
%do i =1 to count(distinct(Person));
proc sgplot data= Original (where=(count = 4))
    scatter x=Date y=QTY/ group = Brand;
run;
end;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain the 'count=4' criteria.  Did you get any errors when submitting your code ?

Comment: It is just subsetting the data

Answer (score 2):

In SAS, the *doing something for each* concept is typically serviced via the `BY` statement.  The Proc will perform the operations you expect and automatically process the data group-wise according to the distinct values of the by variable(s) !

This example demonstrates how the `by` variable value can be placed in the plot title (`#byval1`), as well as suppressing the default byline (`nobyline`) that would show person=*name* as a sub-title.  The `BY PERSON` statement with the optional argument **`NOTSORTED`** means the rows of the group will be formed **row-wise by contiguous value adjacency**, allowing `by` processing to work without error even when the data is not sorted by `Person`.  For safer operation, presort or index the data set by the by variables first.

```
data have; infile datalines dlm='|';
input 
Person $  Date: date11.    QTY      Brand $; 
format date date9.;
datalines;
  Jim   | 01-Aug-2015   |   20    |  Pepsi
  Jim   | 01-Aug-2015   |   20    |  Coke 
  Jim   | 01-Oct-2016   |   30    |  Pepsi
  Jim   | 01-Nov-2016   |   40    |  Sprit 
  Susan | 01-Sep-2015   |   20    |  Dr.Pepper
  Susan | 01-Dec-2016   |   10    |  Sprit 
  Helen | 01-Jan-2016   |   20    |  Coke
  Helen | 01-Feb-2016   |   30    |  Pepsi
run;

title "Scatter for #BYVAL1";
options nobyline;
proc sgplot data=have;
  by person notsorted;
  scatter x=date y=qty / group = brand;
  xaxis interval=month;
  format date monyy7.;
run;
options byline;
title;
```

persons `Jim` `Susan` `Helen` are not in sort order, so if the `NOTSORTED` option was left off there would be an error message and possibly some incomplete output.

Answer (score 1):

To use a do-loop in that manner you will have to write the code within a macro. Also, to get the list of distinct people you can use proc sql's select into: feature.

```
%macro CreatePlots;

proc sql noprint;
select disinct person into: people separated by ' '
from original;
quit;

/* List of people in macro variable */
%put &people;

/* Loop over the list of people */
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&people));
    %let person = %scan(&people,&i);
    /* Print the current person being plotted */
    %put &=person;
    proc sgplot data= Original(where=(person="&person"));
        scatter x=Date y=QTY/ group = Brand;
    run;
%end;
%mend;

%CreatePlots;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't, you add a BY statement. You may need to sort the data ahead of time, by PERSON for this to work but BY group process is efficient.

```
proc sgplot data= Original (where=(count = 4));
     BY PERSON;
    scatter x=Date y=QTY/ group = Brand;
run;
```